# In Google Sites, how do I get "embed" text to behave like "text box" text when screen width changes?

Tags: iframe, google-sites-2016

I am using Google Sites to make a simple website.  I put in an embed block to hold some text because there are some links in that text that are need to be tied to some Javascript behavior.  I figured out that part.

Then, I wanted to make the embed section look like the text box sections.  I copied some of the span settings out of the source to get color and font right and that all looks great on a PC.

Then I switched to a mobile view.  Where the "text box" simply word wraps and expands downward, my "embed" block of text remains the same height and adds a vertical scrollbar.

Attempts:

- I can expand the frame downward in the editor, which fixes it for mobile, but then it has a stupid looking gap for PC.
- I tried disabling the scrollbar in the iframe with JS, which worked, but only the top line of text was visible.
- I tried changing the height of the iframe based on content.  There are several answers on how to do this.  That didn't seem to do anything.
- I changed the height of the frame in the WYSIWYG editor and compared the resulting code before and after the change, but I couldn't figure out what the relevant change in the code was.

My hunch is that the height is limited by some other setting besides the iframe height, but I am somewhat new to this and I could use some guidance.

Thanks.